# How to convert Integers to Byte in C++ so that Unity can understand them after transfer via UDP

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, udp

I need to send two INT16 values as 4 bytes via UDP to Unity.
When I use packet sender and send HEX like e.g. "f1 ff 0f 00", Unity translates respective HEX back to INT in Unity as expected.

However, I don't get this to work in C++.

I can send data from my C++ code as follows:

```C++
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
udp_send client(io_service, "127.0.0.1", "8052");
client.send("F1FF0F00");
```

I am also able to create the right HEX format in C++, representing a HEX Integer (%x format). Unfortunately, these HEX formats all came as array of %x which isn't accepted by the boost send method above.

I tried to send various strings to Unity - however, data that Unity receives are not interpreted correctly - hence my conversion doesn't work as needed.

Below is a routine in C# that does what I am looking for. For my purpose, I need something similar in C++:

```C#
//empty UDP buffer
byte[] UDP_Data = new byte[8];

//add steering data to buffer
Int16 twobytes = (Int16)(15); 
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(twobytes);
UDP_Data[0] = intBytes[0];
UDP_Data[1] = intBytes[1];

//add speed data to buffer
twobytes = (Int16)(-15); 
intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(twobytes);
UDP_Data[0] = intBytes[0];
UDP_Data[1] = intBytes[1];

// send via UDP
client.Send(UDP_Data, UDP_Data.Length, ep)
```

Does anybody know how to rewrite similar code as the above C# in C++ so that data received by Unity are correct?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the C# code is correct? I mean it allocates an array of 8 bytes `UDP_Data` but only uses the first two bytes, but then sends all 8 bytes to the client.

Comment: You are right. The C# isn't correct. Good catch :-)
The logic is that two Int16 have to be transferred by splitting them up into 2 Bytes each and then combine them in a stream of a total of 4 Bytes and send them as UDP_Data via UDP to Unity.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused between text and hex.

This is text `"F1FF0F00"` not hex.

This is hex

```
uint8_t udp_data[4] = { 0xF1, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x00 };
```